# Graphite image rendering leaves a lot of empty space under long legend

Tags: graphite

Let me show you the progression of examples.

Just one metric: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pouuj.png (almost no empty space under the legend)

Four metrics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmqEX.png (a little empty space)

About twenty metrics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP3SE.png (empty space takes almost 20% of height leaving little space for the graph itself - it could be more than two times taller!)

Target is nothing fancy: `sortByName(exclude(some.avg.metric.*,'some_exc'), true)`

Is there a way to fix this, besides moving to Grafana?

I don't want to hide the legend, this is my monitoring tool and I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we use painfully old version of Graphite Web: https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/issues/2498